# Converting MapWritable to a string in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

When I run my output with the toString() method I am getting:

```
#zombie org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable@b779f586
#zombies        org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable@c8008ef9
#zona   org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable@99e061a1
#zoology        org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable@9d0060be
#zzp    org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable@3e52c108
```

Here is my reducer code, how can I get the map values to print out instead?

```
package sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class IntSumReducer 
extends Reducer<Text,MapWritable,Text,MapWritable> {
private MapWritable result = new MapWritable();
String temp = "";
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<MapWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    result.clear();
    for (MapWritable val : values) {
        Iterable<Writable> keys = val.keySet();
        for (Writable k : keys) {
            IntWritable tally = (IntWritable) val.get(k);
            if (result.containsKey(k)) {
                IntWritable tallies = (IntWritable) result.get(k);
                tallies.set(tallies.get() + tally.get());
                temp = toString() + " : " + tallies.get();
                result.put(new Text(temp), tallies);
            } else {
                temp = k.toString() + " : " + tally.get();
                result.put(new Text(temp), tally);
            }
         }
    }
    context.write(key, result);
}
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Adding a class like this should work:

```
class MyMapWritable extends MapWritable {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        Set<Writable> keySet = this.keySet();

        for (Object key : keySet) {
            result.append("{" + key.toString() + " = " + this.get(key) + "}");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
MyMapWritable mw = new MyMapWritable();
mw.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` is a `MapWritable`, and the toString() method is not overridden in MapWritable.
You can create  new class that extends MapWritable and create your own toString() method in it. 
Change your code after that to :

```
public class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,MapWritable,Text,YourMapWritable> {
  private YourMapWritable result = new YourMapWritable();
  String temp = "";
  ...
```

Comment: Hi, I'm doing it wrong cause can't get it to work still.. I made a new class like package sample;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable;

public class ToString extends MapWritable{
 
 public String toString() {
  return this.toString();
 }
}
 and then updated my IntSumReducer class :   public class IntSumReducer
extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,ToString> {

    private ToString result = new ToString();

Comment: You must implement your own method that iterate the `MapWritable` and generate the string. You cannot do `return this.toString();`.